# MySQL show limited number of contacts when showing all contact groups

Tags: mysql

I have an address book referred to as contacts. To help organize contacts I have groups (e.g. family, friends, work). I want to pull say, 4 or 10 examples of contacts to display for each group. This is intended for the group index page where all groups are listed though is not intended to have a full list of contacts per group (that is for the dedicated group page only).

**Groups Table and Columns**

`email_groups`

`id`, `id_user`, `name`

**Contacts Table and Columns**

`email_contacts`

`id`, `id_group`, `id_user`, `name`

I've been working on this but am getting a wrong column name for `c1`.

```
SELECT 
eg.id, 
eg.name, 
(SELECT c1.name FROM email_contacts AS c1 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 0,1) AS contact_1, 
(SELECT c2.name FROM email_contacts AS c1 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 1,1) AS contact_2, 
(SELECT c3.name FROM email_contacts AS c3 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 2,1) AS contact_3, 
(SELECT c4.name FROM email_contacts AS c4 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 3,1) AS contact_4 
FROM email_groups AS eg 
INNER JOIN email_contacts AS ec on ec.id=eg.id_group
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have provided alias `C1` twice in your subqueries i guess it would be `C2` for second subquery , you are trying to select `c2.name` but you have provided the the alias as `c1` **SELECT c2.name FROM email_contacts AS c1**

```
SELECT 
eg.id, 
eg.name, 
(SELECT c1.name FROM email_contacts AS c1 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 0,1) AS contact_1, 
(SELECT c2.name FROM email_contacts AS c2 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 1,1) AS contact_2, 
(SELECT c3.name FROM email_contacts AS c3 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 2,1) AS contact_3, 
(SELECT c4.name FROM email_contacts AS c4 WHERE id_user='1' LIMIT 3,1) AS contact_4 
FROM email_groups AS eg 
INNER JOIN email_contacts AS ec on ec.id=eg.id_group
```

Comment: Ah, I did have it working correctly but I missed that mistake, thank you.